# Changing images when hovering over links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a script to change a static image by hovering over navigation links. It works great, however, the script is very long and I'm guessing there is a much more efficient way to write this code. Can anyone give me tips on a better way to do this?

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a id="1" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="2" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="3" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box">
  <img src="default.jpg"/>                    
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#navigation li a#1').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'image1.jpg');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'default.jpg');
    }
);
$('#navigation li a#2').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'default.jpg');
    }
);
$('#navigation li a#3').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'image3.jpg');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'default.jpg');
    }
);
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qsaw1rz0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new attribute to your divs, in this case we will use **data-filename**. You could even use the index of each element in the list, but if you want to use custom names in your images is better the use a new attribute.

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a id="1" href="#" data-filename="image1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="2" href="#" data-filename="image2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="3" href="#" data-filename="image3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box">
  <img src="default.jpg"/>                    
</div>
```

Simplify your script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#navigation li a').hover(
    function(){
        //we get our current filename and use it for the src
        var linkIndex = $(this).attr("data-filename");
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', linkIndex+'.jpg');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'default.jpg');
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the function from the data. Then you can just bind the same function to all of the links.

**html**

```
  <li><a id="1" href="#" data-img='image1.jpg'>Link 1</a></li>
```

**js**

```
$('#navigation li a').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', $(this).data('img');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        $('.box img').attr('src', 'default.jpg');
    }
);
```